# Swift Spritekit Change Frame Shape

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am making a IOS game in Swift using Spritekit, the player has a triangular mesh, that I create with this code:

```
    let viewpath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(viewpath, nil, 200, 0);

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(viewpath, nil, 0, 400);

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(viewpath, nil, 400, 400);

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(viewpath, nil, 200, 0);

    let playerviewshape = SKShapeNode(path: viewpath);

    playerviewshape.fillColor = SKColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.1)

    playerviewshape.strokeColor = SKColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2)

    playerview = SKSpriteNode(texture: view.textureFromNode(playerviewshape));

    playerview.zPosition = 0;

    playerview.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200);

    player.addChild(playerview);
```

I want to know if any enemies are inside the triangle, So in the update loop I use `if(enemy.intersectsNode(playerview)) {` however this only checks if it is inside the node's frame, Which is a rectangle around the triangle. I have tried using the triangle as a SKShapeNode and I have also tried using containsPoint instead of intersectsNode.

How can I change the frame/the way I detect intersections, so it will only detect the sprites if they are inside the triangle?

Comment: You will have to use SKPhysicsBody if you want that kind of detection

Comment: On a side note,  SKShape still has a ton of problems with it, so I recommend creating your SKShape, then make a texture with the function inside of your view called textureFromNode (Or you can spawn a new SKView, doesn't matter),  and feed that texture into an SKSpriteNode.  Then with your SKPhysicsBody, you should be able to handle collisions based on the desired shape

Comment: @Knight0fDragon How can if i add physics bodys to the nodes how can I stop them affecting each other, .E.G. Pushing each other?

Comment: you set collisionbitmask to 0

Comment: Actually just realised that I should use collisionBitMask.

Comment: why? you said you dont want them pushing

Comment: Sorry, Didn't see your last comment, I meant setting the collision bitmask to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write some code that can be useful to starting to set your physics:

(P.S. I dont know which type was player so I use playerview just to make an example..)

```
enum CollisionTypes: UInt32 {
    case Playerview = 1 // my hero
    case WarField = 2 // the warfield 
    case Enemy1 = 4 // simple enemies type
    case Enemy2 = 8  // 2 level enemies type
    case Enemy3 = 16 // boss enemies type
    case Enemy4 = 32 // boss of the boss enemies type
}


playerview.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
playerview.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.Playerview.rawValue
playerview.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.Enemy1.rawValue | CollisionTypes.Enemy2.rawValue | CollisionTypes.Enemy3.rawValue | CollisionTypes.Enemy4.rawValue
playerview.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
     if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionTypes.Playerview.rawValue &&
            contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == CollisionTypes.Enemy1.rawValue) {
         print("The collision was between the playerview and a enemy1")
     }
     ...
}
```